# Updating with Prepared statement: ORA-00933 error

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm using the following servlet code to update data from my android application. But I'm receiving error as ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. Here is my code

```
try
   {
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxx:xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");
    String query="update offer1 set RCODE=?,EXTENT=?,PHONE=?,DAT=?LOAN=?,SEED=? where OFFERNO=?";
    PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1,r_code);
    ps.setString(2,extent);
    ps.setString(3,phone);
    ps.setDate(4,sqlDate);
    ps.setString(5,loan);
    ps.setString(6,seeds);
    ps.setString(7,offrno);
    int i=ps.executeUpdate();
    out.println("data updated");
}catch(Exception e)
    {
       out.println(e);
    }
```

I couldn't understood the problem. Someone help me what is the mistake in my code and how to use proper code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry for this unvaluable question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error in your UPDATE query:

```
String query="update offer1 set RCODE=?,EXTENT=?,PHONE=?,DAT=?LOAN=?,SEED=? where OFFERNO=?";
```

Comma is missing after DAT=?. Change it to:

```
String query="update offer1 set RCODE=?,EXTENT=?,PHONE=?,DAT=?,LOAN=?,SEED=? where OFFERNO=?";
```